# String concatenation and class function in PHP?

Tags: php, class, string-concatenation

I was writing a simple class. Here is the code:

```
class Book{
    var $title;
    var $publishedDate;

    function Book($title, $publishedDate){
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->publishedDate = $publishedDate;
    }

    function displayBook(){
        echo "Title: " . $this->title . " published on " . $this->publishedDate . "";
    }

    function setAndDisplay($newTitle, $newDate){
        $this->title = $newTitle;
        $this->publishedDate = $newDate;
        echo "The new information is of the book <b>" . $this->displayBook() . "</b><br />";
    }
}
```

And I initialized the class and called the function:

```
$test = new Book("Harry Potter", "2010-1-10");
$test->setAndDisplay("PHP For Beginners", "2010-2-10");
```

And the result is:

```
"Title: PHP For Beginners published on 2010-2-10The new information is of the book"
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
"The new information is of the book **Title: PHP For Beginners published on 2010-2-10**
```

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `displayBook()` method does not return a string (or anything for that matter) so you shouldn't really be using the result in a concatenation.

What's happening is the call to `displayBook()` in the `echo` in `setAndDisplay()` happens *before* the `echo` completes.

You should use different methods for direct output vs string generation, eg

```
public function getBook()
{
    return sprintf('Title: %s published on %s',
                   $this->title,
                   $this->publishedDate);
}

public function displayBook()
{
    echo $this->getBook();
}

public function setAndDisplay($newTitle, $newDate)
{
    $this->title = $newTitle;
    $this->publishedDate = $newDate;
    echo "The new information is of the book <b>", $this->getBook(), "</b><br />";
}
```

Edit: I'd seriously re-evaluate the need for your class to directly `echo` data. This is rarely a good idea.

Edit2: Passing parameters to `echo` is faster than concatenation

Comment: Hmmm... I see. So I must store in a variable first, before do the concatination?

Comment: @wordpress_newbie - Sorry, I'm a slow typist today. See my edit

Comment: Learned another tips => "Passing parameters to echo is faster than concatenation". All the while, I used concatenation(".").

Comment: 1 quick question: Is there any limit of how many arguments you can pass to "echo" function? Sorry, its out of this topic, but I guess, this is a quick/short question, so I dont want to open up a new question.

Comment: The best place for this kind if information is the manual - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php. It's not mentioned so I'd say there's no limit within *reasonable* bounds.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `displayBook()` echos the string. And when you try to append or inject a function that echos something, it will get put at the beginning. You have to replace the dots `.` with commas `,`for it to get placed where you want it.

http://codepad.org/9pfqiRHu